# My javascript and jquery not working in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="javascript" src="despage/javascript/script.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function alert() {
      alert("hello");
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      ("p").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });
    });
  </script>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 style="text-align:center;font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;font-weight: bolder;color:rgb(222, 222, 222);">HEAD</h1></div>
  <p onclick="alert()">this one is for test</p>
</body>
```

I used cdn url for jquery it didnt work ,network connection was stable.simple alert() function onclick on the p tag was working until i wrote that alert function call in the script tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created an *infinitely recursive function* here:

```
function alert() {
  alert("hello");
}
```

When you call `alert()`, it internally calls `alert()`, which internally calls `alert()`, which internally calls `alert()`, and so on forever.

You don't need to write an `alert` function in the browser.  It already has one.  Just remove this function of yours entirely.

---

Additionally, *a string* has no function called `click`:

```
("p").click(/*...*/)
```

You're probably looking to use that string as a jQuery selector:

```
$("p").click(/*...*/)
```

---

Also, don't use inline click handlers:

```
<p onclick="alert()">
```

Remove the handler from there:

```
<p>
```

And, since you're using jQuery, just use jQuery to attach a click handler:

```
$("p").click(/*...*/)
```

---

Overall, it sounds like the click handler you want is simply:

```
$("p").click(function() {   
  $(this).hide();
  alert("hello");
});
```

(Which should, in this structure, still remain inside your `document`'s `ready` handler.)

Comment: why cant we use inline click handler

Comment: @ASWINDEVDR: You *can*, but (1) you generally *shouldn't* and (2) why would you?  You're already attaching a click handler to your `<p>` element(s) in the JavaScript code.  So why wouldn't you just use that?  Why attach two click handlers to the same element(s) in two drastically different ways?

Comment: i was testing whether javascript and jquery was working fine.But mistake was with the code.Thank you for the help bro. Simply